# Get dir of a file

Tags: java, android

I think I have a simple question, but I cant figure it out. I would like to get the directory of a file.

Example: 
path = /mnt/sdcard/music/music.mp3

Should return 'music'

```
public String getDir(String pathAudioFile)
{
    File f = new File(pathAudioFile);

    return  f.???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f.getParentFile().getName()
```

will return just "music", stripping off the leading path elements.

Answer (score 7):

```
f.getParent(); // returns directory String
f.getParentFile(); // returns File directory object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
File file = new File(pathAudioFile);
String parent = file.getParent();
System.out.println("Parent directory is : " + parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getDir(String pathAudioFile)
..
    return  f.getParent();
```

But the code should **not** be return a `String` that represents a `File`.  It **should** return a `File`. <sup>1</sup>

```
public File getDir(String pathAudioFile)
..
    return  f.getParentFile();
```

<sup>1</sup> IMO all methods in the J2SE that are designed to accept a `String` that represents a `File` should be deprecated.  If a method needs a `File`, **give it a `File`!**

---

Extending that philosophy..

```
@deprecated Use getDir(java.io.File) instead.
public File getDir(String pathAudioFile)
{
    return  getDir(new File(pathAudioFile));
}

public File getDir(File audioFile)
{
    return  audioFile.getParentFile();
}
```